# Python word replacement list switch on key word

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, find, key

Does anybody know how to modify this script so that it switches dictionary for every instance of the word "rat"

```
word_replacement = [{'dog': 'Bob', 'cat': 'Sally', 'bird': 'John', 'rat': 'Pat'},
        {'dog': 'Brown', 'cat': 'White', 'bird': 'Black', 'rat': 'Grey'},
        {'dog': 'Bark', 'cat': 'Meow', 'bird': 'Chirp', 'rat': 'Squeek'}]

with open("main.txt") as main:
    words = main.read().split()
 
replaced = []
for y in words:
    replacement = word_replacement.get(y, y)
    replaced.append(replacement)
text = ' '.join(replaced)

 
print (text)

new_main = open("main.txt", 'w')
new_main.write(text)
new_main.close()
```

Sample input:

```
dog bird rat dog cat cat rat bird rat cat dog
```

desired output:

```
Bob John Pat Brown White White Grey Chirp Squeek Sally Bob
```

Comment: Your example right now doesn't work. `word_replacement` is a list (of dicts), not a dict, so `word_replacement.get` does not exist

Comment: As to how: keep an index of which dictionary you want to use. (`word_replacement[index].get`) and if word=='rat', do it +1 with modulo 3 (or instead of hardcoding 3, use len(word_replacement)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has already be pointed out that `word_replacement` is a list so you have to access its elements with an index you'll be incrementing when `rat` is met:

```
word_replacement = [{'dog': 'Bob', 'cat': 'Sally', 'bird': 'John', 'rat': 'Pat'},
        {'dog': 'Brown', 'cat': 'White', 'bird': 'Black', 'rat': 'Grey'},
        {'dog': 'Bark', 'cat': 'Meow', 'bird': 'Chirp', 'rat': 'Squeek'}]

input_str = "dog bird rat dog cat cat rat bird rat cat dog"
words = input_str.split()

replaced = []
dic_list_idx = 0
list_len = len(word_replacement)
for w in words:
    replacement = word_replacement[dic_list_idx % list_len].get(w, w)
    replaced.append(replacement)
    if w == "rat":
        dic_list_idx += 1
text = ' '.join(replaced)


print (text)

new_main = open("main.txt", 'w')
new_main.write(text)
new_main.close()
```

`dic_list_idx % list_len` allows you to start from the first dictionary when you reach the end of the list.

Output:

```
Bob John Pat Brown White White Grey Chirp Squeek Sally Bob
```

Note: in your example it seems there's some confusion between keys and values (shouldn't `bird` be replaced with `John`?)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, but 2 come to mind at first:

1. Have a counter in loop which you increase whenever you get 'rat', and reset to zero if you reach the end:

```
i = 0
for y in words.split():
    replacement = word_replacement[i][y]
    replaced.append(replacement)
    if y == 'rat':
        i += 1
    if i == len(word_replacement):
        i = 0
text = ' '.join(replaced)

print(text)
```

2. Always use the first dictionary in the list, but on every occurrence of word 'rat' pop the first dict and push it in the back :D

```
for y in words.split():
    replacement = word_replacement[0][y]
    replaced.append(replacement)
    if y == 'rat':
        word_replacement.append(word_replacement.pop(0))
text = ' '.join(replaced)
```